# Laravel 4 get the id of created field

Tags: laravel, controller, laravel-4

I am developing a booking form that has data that will fill two tables, users and booking table. In the controller I am getting the input fields and inserting the user fields first, then I do the insert for the booking but I need the id of the user I've just inserted, I have tried many methods without success, this is what I have done in my controller:

```
   $User = new User;
         User::create(array(
        'lastname'=>Input::get('lastname'),
        'name'=>Input::get('name'),
        'address'=>Input::get('address'),
        'cell_phone'=>Input::get('cell_phone'),
        'email'=>Input::get('email')

        ));

    // I try to get the inserted user id here
    $userInserted=$User->id;

    // And here I insert the booking with the user_id
    $Booking = new Booking;
    Booking::create(array(
        'apartment_id'=>Input::get('apartment_id'),
        'user_id'=>$userInserted,
        'date_ini'=>Input::get('date_from'),
        'date_fin'=>Input::get('date_to'),
        'stay_cost'=>Input::get('stay_cost'),
        'stay_days'=>Input::get('stay_days')

        ));
```

The problem is I am not getting the user Id. Any idea way?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assignin it wrong.

```
$newUser = User::create(...);
$insertedUserId = $newUser->id;
```

Your `$User = new User;` makes no sense, because it just initializes emty User Object, but `User::create` sends query to DB to store data and returns inserted Object.

Comment: Thank you, I thought I had the same code, I still can't see the problem, it was this? $User = new User;

Comment: Yes. The are 2 alternative ways: 1) `$user = new User; $user->name = 'John'; $user->save();` or 2) `$user = User::create(['name' => 'John']); `